# Javascript function as argument in setTimout

Tags: javascript

In the following code, "Blast Off!" displays one second after the 1 displays. But, if I change the function call to setTimeout(finish(), 1000) "Blast Off!" displays immediately after 1. Why does including the () change the timing?

```
let countDown= time => {
    let timer = setInterval(function(){
        console.log(time);
        time--;
        if (time==0){
            clearInterval(timer);
            let finish = ()=> {
                console.log("Blast Off!");
            }
            setTimeout(finish, 1000);   
        }
    1000);
};
let startNum = Number(prompt("What number should I start counting down from? "));
countDown(startNum);
```

Trying to understand the difference between `setTimeout(finish, 1000)` and `setTimeout(finish(), 1000)`

Comment: Because adding the `()` calls the function. `setTimeout` expects a function **reference**.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `finish` you are just telling the timeout that you want to run the `finish` function after 1000ms.
On the other hand, when you use `finish()` you are **calling** the function, that is why it runs immediately